# Slider in a stack view wants to resize

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uistackview

I have a stack view with a slider on centre ,and 2 labels on the sides.That stack view it is placed into another stack view with a button after SView . I placed it on the centre of the screen.

It tells me that the frame for stack view will be different at run time,document outline says to me that it wants to be bigger in width.I chose update frames.
This happens infinitely.

Is this a bug ?
Or I am doing this wrong ? 
If yes what I am doing wrong ?
I think this is a bug because this is a beta and the stack view doesn't need to go outside the screen bounds

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your situation in a sample project and was unable to reproduce what you are experiencing on Xcode 7b4 so this may have indeed been a bug.  I tried the following layouts:

1. `[Label | Slider | Label]
            Button`

Labels and slider are in a horizontal UIStackView. Button and horizontal stack are inside of a vertical UIStackView

2. `[[Label | Slider | Label ][ Button ]]`

Labels and slider are in a horizontal UIStackView. Button and horizontal stack are inside of another horizontal UIStackView.

Both times I centered the top-level stack view and was able to use the Storyboard's 'Update Frames' to get my layout working.

Comment: My layout is 1, and I put the vertical stack view in the center.(with constraints ) I fixed that by putting constraints at leading and trailing ,and vertical center